# Can one connect to a MySQL database with an SSH tunnel using ODBC in SSRS?

Tags: ssh, reporting-services, odbc

I'm building a report in SSRS that needs to pull data off of a MySQL server my company only allows connection to via SSH. Connecting to MySQL in SSRS means using ODBC, and while I have PuTTY set to be able to connect to it on my local machine, how would I make it so that any user who would want to run the report would be able to do so without also setting PuTTY up on their machines and walking them through signing in to use it?

Answer (score 3):

And the answer is: yes! You just cannot do it with the default Connector/ODBC driver that comes with MySQL. Apparently this has been a feature request for [nearly a decade](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=48880), but has never been fulfilled.

So, if you want SSRS to connect to a MySQL database through an SSH tunnel, you'll either need to set your reporting server up with an SSH client like PuTTY and have it connect through to pull data off of that database (which means making sure to restart PuTTY whenever it goes to sleep or cuts connection), or you'll need to go and buy this [Devart MySQL ODBC driver](https://www.devart.com/odbc/mysql/docs/general_info.htm) that allows for SSH tunneling without the need for an external SSH client.
Or option 3 is to write your own MySQL ODBC driver, I guess. May as well throw that one out there for completeness.

Sucks that I have to get this expensed, but now you know. :)